# Undefined references linking to libav* with mingw

Tags: linker, ffmpeg, mingw, libav

**Overview**

I'm trying to build one of the example files from the `ffmpeg` src directory on Windows using mingw, but I get a ton of undefined references to a bunch of the `libav*` functions.

I've already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625468/libav-linking-error-undefined-references) and several others, but none of them resolved my issue. Specifically, I am *not* building a C++ program, and I am *not* using `g++`, so the whole `extern "C"` thing does not apply (in fact I already tried it, and it didn't work).

**Details**

I've downloaded [Zeranoe](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)'s [64-bit dev package](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/dev/ffmpeg-20131017-git-a7e3006-win64-dev.7z), and unpacked it to `C:\apps\pf\ffmpeg`. Now I'm just trying to build the `decoding_encoding.c` file in `doc/examples`. My CWD is `C:\apps\pf\ffmpeg\doc\examples`, and my commands look like this (line-continuation and comments added):

```
#Compile
gcc -o decoding_encoding.obj -c -IC:\apps\pf\ffmpeg\include decoding_encoding.c

#Link
gcc -o decoding_encoding.exe decoding_encoding.obj \
    -LC:\apps\pf\ffmpeg\lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavdevice \
    -lavfilter -lavutil -lswscale -lm
```

The compile works fine, but the link spits out these errors:

```
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `av_get_channel_layout_nb_channels'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x131): undefined reference to `avcodec_find_encoder'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x179): undefined reference to `avcodec_alloc_context3'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x1fa): undefined reference to `av_get_sample_fmt_name'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x26c): undefined reference to `av_get_channel_layout_nb_channels'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x28f): undefined reference to `avcodec_open2'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x313): undefined reference to `avcodec_alloc_frame'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x3c8): undefined reference to `av_samples_get_buffer_size'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x3d6): undefined reference to `av_malloc'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x44f): undefined reference to `avcodec_fill_audio_frame'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x4ce): undefined reference to `av_init_packet'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x5c2): undefined reference to `avcodec_encode_audio2'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x63a): undefined reference to `av_free_packet'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x680): undefined reference to `avcodec_encode_audio2'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x6f8): undefined reference to `av_free_packet'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x722): undefined reference to `av_freep'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x72d): undefined reference to `avcodec_free_frame'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x738): undefined reference to `avcodec_close'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x743): undefined reference to `av_free'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x77b): undefined reference to `av_init_packet'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x7a1): undefined reference to `avcodec_find_decoder'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x7e9): undefined reference to `avcodec_alloc_context3'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x840): undefined reference to `avcodec_open2'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x8e6): undefined reference to `av_free'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x947): undefined reference to `avcodec_alloc_frame'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x999): undefined reference to `avcodec_get_frame_defaults'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x9c2): undefined reference to `avcodec_decode_audio4'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0xa44): undefined reference to `av_samples_get_buffer_size'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0xb7d): undefined reference to `avcodec_close'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0xb88): undefined reference to `av_free'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0xb96): undefined reference to `avcodec_free_frame'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0xbe4): undefined reference to `avcodec_find_encoder'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0xc2c): undefined reference to `avcodec_alloc_context3'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0xcee): undefined reference to `av_opt_set'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0xd08): undefined reference to `avcodec_open2'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0xd8c): undefined reference to `avcodec_alloc_frame'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0xe2f): undefined reference to `av_image_alloc'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0xe83): undefined reference to `av_init_packet'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0xfd3): undefined reference to `avcodec_encode_video2'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x105f): undefined reference to `av_free_packet'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x10a9): undefined reference to `avcodec_encode_video2'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x1135): undefined reference to `av_free_packet'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x117e): undefined reference to `avcodec_close'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x1189): undefined reference to `av_free'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x1194): undefined reference to `av_freep'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x119f): undefined reference to `avcodec_free_frame'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x1272): undefined reference to `avcodec_decode_video2'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x13b1): undefined reference to `av_init_packet'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x13fa): undefined reference to `avcodec_find_decoder'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x1442): undefined reference to `avcodec_alloc_context3'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x14ba): undefined reference to `avcodec_open2'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x153e): undefined reference to `avcodec_alloc_frame'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x1674): undefined reference to `avcodec_close'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x167f): undefined reference to `av_free'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x168a): undefined reference to `avcodec_free_frame'
decoding_encoding.obj:decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x16ab): undefined reference to `avcodec_register_all'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: @Haroogan: Nice, thanks! Installing MinGW-w64 was a nightmare, but once I got it installed, I can finally build against libav*. If you post that as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can already see in the `README` that this library was built with MinGW-w64 and is targeting 64-bit. Plain old MinGW does not support 64-bit targets. Therefore, if you are using MinGW, then of course it cannot link against 64-bit libraries, hence you experience these errors.

To solve your problem, simply install MinGW-w64. I highly recommend to download its distribution from **[here](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/download.php#mingw-builds)**. There is no installation nightmare: just unpack, add `bin` to the `PATH` environment variable and you are good to go.

Finally, take a look at this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425482/windows-c-compiler-with-full-c11-support-should-work-with-qt/19425966#19425966)**, it might be useful for you to understand who is who.

Comment: Eh, the installation nightmare comes when you visit http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/, but you're right, the mingw-builds installer was fuss-free. Unrelated but a major bummer for me, mingw-w64 doesn't have a real implementation of libscrnsave, so it can't replace mingw for me.

Comment: It contains `libscrnsave.a`. Look carefully.

Comment: It's there, but look _more_ carefully =) It's only 1KB and doesn't actually implement anything. Apparently if you look at the src code it's all commented out with `#if 0`. Maybe another day I'll uncomment it and try to build mingw-w64 from src.

Comment: OK, I see your point. Well, that's strange, probably you could ask them on the mailing list about it, guys are usually quite helpful there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It looks like it's already been brought up, just back in June. Hopefully there will be a fix out soon: http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/discussion/723798/thread/54ec11c2/

Comment: Just an FYI, the previous link was just on the project's forum, I've now submitted it as a bug to the project: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/351/

Answer (score 1):

Just to close the loop on this, I wasn't happy with mingw-w64 for my purposes, specifically because it lacks a useful implementation of `libscrnsave`. So instead I built `libav` from source using standard `mingw`.

Building `libav` was fairly simple, once I figured it all out. It goes like this:

1. Download and install the mingw installer from http://www.mingw.org/.
2. Use the mingw installer to install MSYS.
3. Download yasm from http://yasm.tortall.net/Download.html
4. Renamed the downloaded yasm executable to just `yasm.exe`, and place it in the MSYS directory, under `bin`.
5. Download the libav sources from https://libav.org/download.html
6. Unpack the libav sources.
7. Open MSYS and `cd` to wherever the libav sources are.
8. In MSYS, run `./configure --disable-pthreads --disable-w32threads --prefix=/c/apps/pf/libav` (those are the options that worked for me, the `--prefix` option specifies where to install the libraries when you run `make install`, mine places them under `C:\apps\pf\libav`).
9. Once that completes, run `make`, then `make install`.

Once the libraries were built, I was able to link against them building from the normal windows command line using standard mingw.

To use with `pkg-config`, you need to add the `lib/pkgconfig` directory under the installed location to the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` env variable. To properly build, you should use `pkg-config <LIBS> --cflags --libs` to get the correct flags to pass to `gcc`, where `<LIBS>` is the list of libav libraries you need to build against. It doesn't do any harm to just include all of the libav libraries, but order matters. The following order seems to work for me: `libavdevice libavformat libavcodec libavfilter libswscale libavresample libavutil`.

Ultimately, the command line I used that worked looked like this (line continuation and comments added):

```
#Compile
gcc -o decoding_encoding.obj -c -IC:\apps\pf\libav\include decoding_encoding.c

#Link
gcc -o decoding_encoding.exe decoding_encoding.obj -LC:\apps\pf\libav\lib \
    -lavdevice -lavfilter -lavformat -lavcodec -lswscale -lavresample \
    -lavicap32 -lws2_32 -lpsapi -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lavutil -lm
```