# "undefined reference" error messages when trying to compile spdif-loop

Tags: c, linux, makefile, libav

I'm trying to compile [spdif-loop](https://github.com/corecode/spdif-loop) on my machine running Ubuntu 14.04. It says on the GitHub page that the requirements are *ffmpeg* or *libav* and *libao*. I have only very little experience with this, but I thought I'd look at the make file for more details and found this line:

```
LDFLAGS+=       -lavcodec -lavformat -lavdevice -lavutil -lao -lm
```

My guess was that I can install the necessary dependencies like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavdevice-dev libavutil-dev libao-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libao-dev is already the newest version.
libavcodec-dev is already the newest version.
libavdevice-dev is already the newest version.
libavformat-dev is already the newest version.
libavutil-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
```

When I try to compile I get the following result:

```
livewire@za20:~/Projects/Software/spdif-loop$ make
cc -Wall -std=c99 -g  -lavcodec -lavformat -lavdevice -lavutil -lao -lm  spdif-loop.c   -o spdif-loop
/tmp/ccGCH40C.o: In function `alsa_reader':
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:41: undefined reference to `av_read_frame'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:80: undefined reference to `av_free_packet'
/tmp/ccGCH40C.o: In function `probe_codec':
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:91: undefined reference to `av_init_packet'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:92: undefined reference to `av_read_frame'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:95: undefined reference to `av_free_packet'
/tmp/ccGCH40C.o: In function `open_output':
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:118: undefined reference to `ao_open_live'
/tmp/ccGCH40C.o: In function `test_audio_out':
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:151: undefined reference to `cos'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:160: undefined reference to `ao_play'
/tmp/ccGCH40C.o: In function `main':
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:209: undefined reference to `av_register_all'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:210: undefined reference to `avcodec_register_all'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:211: undefined reference to `avdevice_register_all'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:212: undefined reference to `ao_initialize'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:216: undefined reference to `ao_append_option'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:220: undefined reference to `ao_default_driver_id'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:222: undefined reference to `ao_driver_id'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:232: undefined reference to `av_find_input_format'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:236: undefined reference to `av_find_input_format'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:241: undefined reference to `av_malloc'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:253: undefined reference to `avformat_close_input'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:255: undefined reference to `avformat_close_input'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:257: undefined reference to `ao_close'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:265: undefined reference to `avformat_alloc_context'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:269: undefined reference to `avformat_open_input'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:275: undefined reference to `av_init_packet'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:277: undefined reference to `avio_alloc_context'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:281: undefined reference to `avformat_open_input'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:290: undefined reference to `avcodec_find_decoder'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:296: undefined reference to `avcodec_alloc_context3'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:300: undefined reference to `avcodec_open2'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:304: undefined reference to `av_init_packet'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:311: undefined reference to `av_free_packet'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:312: undefined reference to `av_read_frame'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:320: undefined reference to `avcodec_get_frame_defaults'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:322: undefined reference to `avcodec_decode_audio4'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:339: undefined reference to `av_get_bytes_per_sample'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:346: undefined reference to `av_samples_get_buffer_size'
/home/livewire/Projects/Software/spdif-loop/spdif-loop.c:370: undefined reference to `ao_play'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [spdif-loop] Error 1
```

More guesswork trying to find or fix the issue:

```
livewire@za20:~/Projects/Software/spdif-loop$ grep av_read_frame /usr/include/libavformat/*
/usr/include/libavformat/avformat.h: * avformat_open_input() function for opening a file, av_read_frame() for
/usr/include/libavformat/avformat.h: * av_read_frame() on it. Each call, if successful, will return an AVPacket
/usr/include/libavformat/avformat.h: * until the next av_read_frame() call or closing the file. If the caller
/usr/include/libavformat/avformat.h:    /* av_read_frame() support */
/usr/include/libavformat/avformat.h:     * appear in av_read_frame().
/usr/include/libavformat/avformat.h: * Use av_read_frame() instead.
/usr/include/libavformat/avformat.h: * av_read_frame() or until av_close_input_file(). Otherwise the packet is valid
/usr/include/libavformat/avformat.h:int av_read_frame(AVFormatContext *s, AVPacket *pkt);
```

So the header file and a function within that file exists, I guess?

I tried searching around, I found a few similar questions with more complex make files for Android projects, I think that is the wrong direction. I also found [this note in the FAQ](http://libav.org/faq.html#I_0027m-using-Libav-from-within-my-C_002b_002b-application-but-the-linker-complains-about-missing-symbols-which-seem-to-be-available_002e), but I thought this is a C program not C++. And I just looked at similar questions suggested to me.

As I said, I have almost no experience, can you tell me please what I am doing wrong, what I am missing or what needs to be added to make this to build properly?

I also tried

```
LDFLAGS+=       -lavcodec -lavformat -lavdevice -lavutil -lao -lm -L/usr/include/libavformat
```

and

```
LDFLAGS+=       -lavcodec -lavformat -lavdevice -lavutil -lao -lm -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

in the make file, without success or progress.

Comment: See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625468/libav-linking-error-undefined-references

Comment: Did you run the ./configure script that should be in the directory of the program? It verifies if you have all the components to compile the program in a correct way!

Comment: @SergioFormiggini `ls -la` doesn't list such a file in the directory and `./configure` gives me `-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory` it seems to be a very simple program consisting only of one file, and information on GitHub says it's C.

Comment: I downloaded it, I see, it's a very little program! But I cannot compile because I don't have libao! ...

Comment: This way compiles: cc -Wall -std=c99 -g  spdif-loop.c -lavcodec -lavformat -lavdevice -lavutil -lao -lm  -o spdif-loop

Comment: This behaviour is due to a boring problem relevant to the libraries parsing order the compiler uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following Makefile:

```
PROG=   spdif-loop

CFLAGS+=        -Wall -std=c99 -g
LDFLAGS+=       -lavcodec -lavformat -lavdevice -lavutil -lao -lm

all: ${PROG}

$(PROG): $(PROG).c
        cc $(CFLAGS) $(PROG).c $(LDFLAGS) -o $(PROG)
clean:
        -rm -f ${PROG}
```

On my Ubuntu 14.xx it compiles!

Comment: I tried moving the old Makefile to Makefile.old and pasted yours into a new, then ran `make`, result `make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.` What was I supposed to do instead?

Comment: Strange! Run make clean, then re-run make! The reply you had means the program already exists!